# What is the difference between tags islamic-rules, islamic-law and islamic-ruling?

Tags: discussion, tag, tag-synonyms

At time of this writing:

- [islamic-rules](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-rules)× 427
   **Question relating to shariah or Islamic law, based on the teachings of the Qur'an and Sunnah.**
- [islamic-law](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-law)× 95
   **indicates that the question demands a solution or suggestion from Islamic sources, viz. Quran and Ahadith**
- and [islamic-ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-ruling)× 17

Personally, I see no difference between the definitions of [islamic-rules](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-rules) and [islamic-law](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-law). Probably, they should be made synonyms?

And [islamic-ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-ruling) has no definition and should probably be merged with [islamic-rules](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-rules)?

Comment: +1. Always wondered about those tags!

Comment: @shoe rat, Well done, you inquired an interesting question. accidentally it was my question as well, but I forgot to inquired it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From perusing the top-voted questions on each tag, here's my analysis:

- [islamic-rules](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-rules) and [islamic-ruling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-ruling) seem to be exactly the same thing (I wouldn't be surprised if -ruling actually originated as a mistyped -rules) which looks to be a general tag for "What does Islam say about…" or "Is such-and-such permitted in Islam…" style questions.
- [islamic-law](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-law) doesn't appear to be much different, but it does seem to tend towards more government-based questions (as does, to further complicate things, [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia) in pretty much the same manner).

While I can sorta recognize the value of keeping "rules for Muslims" and "rules for Governments" separate, I don't really see why that needs its own tag over simply double-tagging with [islamic-rules](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-rules) (or whatever) and [islamic-government](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-government).

And even though [islamic-law](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-law) tends toward government-related questions, its use is still very inconsistent.  Many of the questions under the tag are clearly more in-line with the [islamic-rules](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-rules) category above.

I really don't see the value in maintaining separate tags in this case.  Too open to confusion, and too little actual payoff.

So unless someone is able to present a compelling argument toward keeping them separate (and given that this meta question has been up for two weeks and received zero love, I'm not holding my breath) I propose simply merging-and-synonyming all three of them to [sharia](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharia).

And then we can go about figuring out how exactly this whole conflation should even be being *used*: Even when we all agree that these tags are actually the same thing, I'm still not convinced anyone really knows what that "same thing" is supposed to *be*.  It mostly just looks like a catch-all for "I'm asking something that probably involves a rule somehow".

[But that's a whole other discussion.](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1422/22)

Comment: I am all for merging

Comment: It is pretty a perfect answer. Since it could be the question of many user about their difference.....